# PostgreSQL parallel query not working on CTAS

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Hi have a query that looks like this:

```
create unlogged table analytics.processor_data as
select col_a, col_b
from tbl_a a
         join tbl_b b
              on a.id = b.id;
```

It's all good, however, it does not trigger parallel processes and takes 45 mins+. Now, if i make a materialized view:

```
create materialized view mv_tbl_b as
select *
from tbl_b;
```

And then do:

```
create unlogged table analytics.processor_data as
select col_a, col_b
from tbl_a a
         join mv_tbl_b b
              on a.id = b.id;
```

Then i see all the processes running and it takes a couple of minutes. Both tables have the same indexes. What is making the difference here?

Comment: What is your Postgres version?

Comment: Please show the definition of these tables (if they are tables...).